# onTouchEvent cannot detected buttom of screen

Tags: android

in my application i get the dimension of Screen with bellow code, i want to draw circle in all of the screen at a certain distance from each other in proportion to the scale screen size:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       Log.i("DRAW", event.getX() + "  , " + event.getY());
       return super.onTouchEvent(event);
   }
```

and in my case it works well and return 480*800;
now i want to click on point 240*800 or 240*750 , but when i touch buttom of screen,for height insted of 800 or 780 or... ,return 680!
In fact, the maximum value for my height is not 800 but gives less
Why is this happening?
How do I calculate this ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because it excludes the navigation bar height